# How to retain a service's data between components in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular

I would like to maintain a log that is available to several modules in my Angular 8 system. So I created the following service:

```
(...)
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogService {
    _log: string[] = [];
    
    constructor() { }
    
    log(labelMsg: string, msg?: string | object) {
        if (msg && typeof msg != 'string')
            msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
        
        msg = msg ? `${labelMsg}: ${msg}` : labelMsg;
        this._log.push(`[${moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS")}] - ${msg}`);
    }
    
    show() {
        if (this._log.length)
            this._log.forEach(l=>console.log(l));
        else 
            console.log('Empty log');
        
    }
}
```

But the problem is that when I load I inject it on several components, I get a per-component instance. I mean I log things in app-init, MainComponent and AboutComponent. And each time I change components, .show will output "Empty log".
I don't want to persist this data. I want it to live only in the frontend.

How can I retain the data between components ?

Comment: Did you try using the providers in your app.module.ts instead of the provideIn property?

Comment: Please share the constructor of your components.

Comment: If the service is `providedIn: root` that means it is going to be a singleton. Just make sure that you don't provide the `LogService` in any module. When you provide a server in the `providers` array, the module/component will get a separate instance.

Comment: You probably declared the service in the providers array of your components metadata. That's how you declare a service when you want a new instance in your component. Remove it from the component metadata and it should use the same instance for all components.

Comment: if you inject the service in the constructor of your components `constructor(private logService:LogService){}` -and in any place more- should **not** happen (**not** include in provider of any module or in provider of component). Other think is that you're not using correct the "links" and each link reload the app -each time reload an app, the service is empty-. I don't know what more can happens :(

Comment: @Eliseo you pointed it correctly. It was the links. I wasn't using the router in some of them. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.  Thanks to all that pointed other possible problems.